# Failed to execute 'registerProtocolHandler' on 'Navigator': The scheme 'message' doesn't belong to the scheme whitelist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to use,

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("message",
                                  "http://localhost/?uri=%s",
                                  "message handler")
```

But getting this error,

```
Failed to execute 'registerProtocolHandler' on 'Navigator': The scheme 'message' doesn't belong to the scheme whitelist.
```

Actually I have mobile app. The server returning custom protocol to mobile. I am testing this on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Protocols that are not on the whitelist need to have "web+" prepended in Chrome. In your case, try "web+message". According to the Google developers site:

> The following protocols do not need a "web+" prefix: "mailto", "mms", "nntp", "rtsp", "webcal".

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/06/Registering-a-custom-protocol-handler

Comment: "bitcoin","geo","im","irc","ircs","magnet","mailto","mms","news","nntp","openpgp4fpr","sip","sms","smsto","ssh","tel","urn","webcal","wtai","xmpp" dont need web+
source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register handler with URL `http://www.example.com/` then your script (the one, that calls `navigator.registerProtocolHanlder`) must be loaded from the same domain, that is `http://www.example.com/`. After reading this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler

and this [How does the Spotify web browser button interact with the Spotify app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112822/how-does-the-spotify-web-browser-button-interact-with-the-spotify-app) (the last answer is very complete) I think you need to configure your about:config :

`gecko.handlerService.allowRegisterFromDifferentHost` pref to `true` in `about:config`

Hopes this help you.

Comment: It is from same domain localhost. I am using chrome. Also any possible way to execute js in this case